# Georeference a dataset in Carto with imported data

Tags: carto, geocoding

I have a number of datasets (in CSV format) that I would like to upload into Carto - the issue is that the dataset with the postal code/georeference data is separate. I would like to upload my data and then use the dataset with georeferenced data (postal code) to display on a carto map.

Comment: Can you share with us a little bit more of information? Do the two datasets have a common column (key) to join them? Maybe you can share a screenshot of the header (1st 4-5 rows) of both datasets.